# Font size names and defaults from theme.json for paragraph blocks in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using `theme.json` to set font sizes for paragraph blocks, like so...

```
...
"core/paragraph": {
    "typography": {
        "customFontSize": false,
        "customLineHeight": false,
        "dropCap": true,
        "fontSizes": [
            {
                "name": "Small",
                "slug": "small",
                "size": "clamp(14px, 1.25, 28px)"
            },
            {
                "name": "Medium",
                "slug": "medium",
                "size": "18px"
            }
        ]
    }
},
...
```

This works fine and the font sizes are selectable when a paragraph is added to the page, but the font size names come through as integers, 1 & 2:

[image: paragraph font sizes]

When I change the value of `small` to be a pixel size like `14px` then the names are the pixel sizes without 'px':

[image: paragraph font sizes]

Two questions:

- How can I set meaningful font size names to appear in the editor sidebar?
- How can I set a default font size that is pre-selected?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you testing with and do you also have the Gutenberg plugin enabled?

Comment: Using 5.9.2 without the Gutenburg plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example with "small" set to `clamp(14px, 1.25, 28px)` the [Font Size Picker](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/e0d70221a88b4969e7b8819843e3a16842992572/packages/components/src/font-size-picker) component attempts to convert the value to an integer but unfortunately, parseInt() does not like "clamp". Instead, the index of the selected font size is displayed in the UI. If you use sizes that are *px* or *em* it will display an integer value as expected.

**Eg.** Using clamp

[image: Using clamp]

**Eg.** Using px

[image: Using pixels]

If you have more than **five** font sizes set, the component will instead render a drop down list / select of the font size names:

[image: More than five font sizes]

It's potentially an oversight in the way "clamp" is handled, but also there are many changes happening to theme.json and building block based themes is still very much in development, so this could change..

Tested in WordPress 5.9.2, no Gutenberg plugin.

Comment: OK interesting. I guess I will live with it until updates are made to the way theme.json handles size names. Maybe they could add a "label" key

Comment: @koosa I agree, a label key seems obvious, though I also see the use case for the numeric size of a font makes sense for Editors/Users who just focus on setting the size. If you hover over the size, it does display the name as a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

I like the direction that Gutenberg is heading, but it's unpolished things like this that really highlight that it's still beta software. I had a client email me today who had accidentally changed the font size of a paragraph, and wasn't sure how to fix it up - all she could see were some font size buttons labeled "1", "2" and "3". Sure, hovering over the buttons shows the label as a tooltip but this is a pretty broken user interface.

I added a bit of hacky CSS to sort it out for now (I'm sure this will break with the next Gutenberg release...):

```
/* use the font size name as the button label */
.components-font-size-picker__controls button::after {
    content: attr(aria-label);
}

/* hide the original label ("1", "2", ...) and the tooltip */
.components-font-size-picker__controls button div,
.components-font-size-picker__controls button span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```